# Set Bootstrap Modal to have same width as the column where it's placed in

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Assuming a 2 columns Bootstrap layout with a Modal placed into the `col-sm-9` column, is it possible to have the modal to have the width of the `col-sm-9` column and not to cover the entire screen?

Basicall what I would like to achieve is to have column `col-sm-3` always visible

```
 <div class="col-sm-3">
  <h1>Headline</h1>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-9">
  <p>Something</p>
  <button class="btn modal-trigger">Trigger Modal</button>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id="modal-car" class="modal-body">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Continue to play</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

EDIT: I tried what @MilanDemoniack suggestted but it did not worked. My `container` is boxed so it's **not** container-fluid but the modal extends till the end

[image]

Comment: Maybe you don't need a modal window, something else to do the job, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if what you want to do is to have a layout where your `"col-sm-3"` would be on the left side of the screen and the `"col-sm-9"` on the right side of the screen, but if it is, here's what I propose :
[image]

**1)** What you want is to have the modal to be as "large" as the `"col-sm-9"`.
The `"col-sm-9"` is a parent of the modal. So you'll need to keep the `"width: 100%"` on the modal. What you must delete from bootstrap class is the `"left: 0"` which will extend the modal from the left corner and "override" the size of the modal + pass over the left block `"col-sm-3"`.
(check the first picture)

[image]

**2)** On the `"modal-dialog"` class, you need to take out the `"max-width : 500px"` that sets the width of your modal box. Now, your modal box will be as large of the `"col-sm-9"`.
(check the second picture)
[image]

Here's the HTML code :
(I had to change the `data-bs-toggle="modal"` `data-bs-target="#exampleModal"` of the button for the modal to open)

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <h1>Headline</h1>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-9">
     <p>Something</p>
     <button class="btn modal-trigger" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">Trigger Modal</button>
     <!-- Modal -->
     <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModal" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content">
                   <div id="modal-car" class="modal-body">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                   </div>
                   <div class="modal-footer">
                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Continue to play</button>
                   </div>
              </div>
           </div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

---

**Update :**

If you want your modal to follow more **media query rules**, set them on both the **parent** and the **modal** (see picture below). That way, it will be container-fluid.

*Do not forget to take out the `"width :100%"` from the modal*

[image]

Comment: Hi @MilanDemoniack. When I do as you suggested the modal starts in the col-sm-9 but it goes till the end of the screen even if col-sm-9 it's in the container.

I updated my question with a screenshot

Comment: I believe it's not container fluid because "col-sm-9" is a media query saying "when on small screen do 9/12 of the parent's size". So if you're not on a sm-screen, you're not in a media query for the modal. So it gets back to its usual "width: 100%"... see what I mean ? What is is you want when you not on "mobile" regarding the modal's width ?

Comment: @A-creative I updated the answer with a picture example. Let me know if it's what you're looking for

Comment: any update on your problem ?

Comment: Yes thanks! I could solve it

Comment: @A-creative great ! Cheers